# How to remove KVO observer of self in UIButton category?

Tags: ios, objective-c, categories, key-value-observing, dealloc

At the begining I have to mention that I don't want to subclassing UIButton due to any other reasons.

Let's assume we have UIButton category which, along with some formatting methods, is also observing on self state changes (enabled, highlighted, selected) to invoke fancy button formatting based on CALayer.

I've managed to set observer for that but while UIButton is deallocating I should also remove it as a observer of itself.

Found already possible solutions:

**1) SFObservers** - crafted global automatic remover of all in-app NSNotificationCenter and KVO observers: http://www.merowing.info/2012/03/automatic-removal-of-nsnotificationcenter-or-kvo-observers/

**2) Associate another dummy object** to UIButton to obtain my own dealloc mentioned here: [Hooking end of ARC dealloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14616119/hooking-end-of-arc-dealloc/14616215#14616215) 
and its ready-to-use solution here: https://github.com/krzysztofzablocki/NSObject-SFExecuteOnDealloc

But...

**Question: Isn't there any simpler solution for that, like for example observing self dealloc?**
Maybe, I don't need to remove KVO of self (deallocated object won't send any changes to itself)?

My current code:

```
#pragma mark - State changes KVO

// Define context
static void * atwContext = &atwContext;

// Method to register for state changes notifications
- (void)atwStartObservingStateChanges {
    [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"enabled" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew|NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:atwContext];
}

// Method to receive all registered state changes notifications
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if (context == atwContext) {
        if ([@"enabled" isEqualToString:keyPath]) {

            NSNumber *newState = [change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey];
            NSNumber *oldState = [change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeOldKey];

            if (oldState && [newState isEqualToNumber:oldState]) {
                NSLog(@"Enabled state has not changed");
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Enabled state has changed to %d", [object isEnabled]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might be better off subclassing `UIButton` and overriding the relevant methods.

Comment: Yep, but this is not my case. I don't want to subclassing UIButton due to any other reasons.

Comment: Instead of observing the state changes via KVO, could you just add yourself as a target/action pair for each of the events that trigger state changes (UIEventTouchDown, UIEventTouchUpInside, etc)?

Comment: Acually, I do that, but what about disabled state? I don't want to make pair messages like [button setEnabled:NO] and [button applyFancyDisabledStyle].